# How can I write into a string like I write into a char[]

Tags: c++

For example, if I have this function:

```
void read(std::string& s)
{
    std::cin >> s;
}
```

and the input

```
first sentence
```

s will contain 'first' only.

If I would've used something like:

```
void read(char array[100])
{
    std::cin.get(array, 100);
}
```

for the same input, I would've got "first sentence".

Is there any way to achieve the same effect using std::string?

This might happen (I think) because cin.get with char[] takes all the characters, even blank spaces, because it ends when it detects an end-of-line character, but cin with string stops when it encounters a space character. (just like cin>> does when being used with char[]).

So, I think that I need a cin.get() which would work for std::string.

I'm thinking about reading into a char array and then using the char* constructor of the string in order to convert the char array into a string, but I think there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, s);` to read a line into a string.

Comment: @Eljay yep, that was the answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Tip: Don't pass in arbitrary array sizes like `char array[100]`. Just do `char* array` or `char array[]`, whatever you prefer. The size should be specified as a separate argument if relevant.

Comment: @tadman I dynamically allocate memory using char*, new, delete everytime. This was just for testing purposes. I didn't know about char array[] though - I'll look into it though, thanks :)

Comment: In C++ it's best to stay away from C strings whenever possible, buffer overflows are a nightmare and `std::string` solves this problem very well. When you do need to use them the `char*` or `char[]` versions make it clear they're of arbitrary length, which is how they should be treated unless otherwise specified. *Always* pass through a size parameter that indicates how big these are when doing any reads or writes to avoid overflows which lead to abrupt segmentation faults or worse.

Comment: @tadman I understand. So string is way better than char*. As far as I understand, string is basically an improvement to char*. Is there something similar for int* ?

Comment: `std::vector` is the default replacement for C arrays, so `std::vector<int>`. This applies to anything you need an arbitrary-sized list of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

```
void read(std::string& s)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

Comment: that's right, now it works. Thanks :) I'll accept your answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getline to input the whole string `std::getline(std::cin, s);`

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

void read(string& s) {
    getline(cin, s);
}
```

Use above code for reading whole line instead of first word.

Comment: Please, don't employ `using namespace std`. It's a bad habit to get into.